# BIRT report with an optional currency parameter - how to specify the parameter in both the ide and the maximo gui

Tags: parameters, currency, birt, maximo

I have a report for maximo 7.6.1.3 that is written for Birt. It has a parameter that is representative of a minimum currency value the report should output data for, that is however optional. I have selected the 'currency' format and datatype of decimal.
When I run it in the birt ide it runs fine whether I put a value in for the parameter or not, but when I run it in Maximo and don't enter any value for the parameter it blows up. I have only a display value for the parameter in the Maximo GUI. Any suggestions on getting this to work? I want the user to be able to enter a minimum and maximum currency amount, or to leave those parameters blank.